# splitting address with - using split() results in wierd 5 digits

Tags: google-sheets

kinda stumped with the split function, was wondering if someone can help me out.

I have a list of addresses where I'm trying to split the number and street name. These addresses have hypens in them so for example.
10-09 Main St
So i used =SPLIT(A1, " ") <- Column A has all the addresses.

The result i get is = 43017 Main    St

I could use the menu tab **Data >>** **Split text to columns** but I'm trying to automate it using a script. Is there a way to force the split function to treat the data as text and not as a number?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This will work with these two user defined functions. Assuming your address is in A1.

```
function nbr(range) {
  var addr = range.split(" ");
  return addr[0];// just the nbr 
 }
function street(range) {
  var addr = range.split(" ");
  var array=[]
  for(var i=1;i<addr.length;i++){
     array.push(addr[i]) //create an array of split addr starting with second element
  }
   return array.toString().replace(/,/g," ")// convert array to string and  replace all commas with soaces
}
```

In B1 put =nbr(A1) and in C1 put =street(A1)

Comment: Can confirm this works. Also: just found out you can apparently write your own functions in Google Spreadsheets - learn something every day :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the column types to `flat text`? I was more-or-less able to replicate the behaviour when I set the column type to `number`, but when I changed the type to `flat text`, it behaved as expected.

Try Layout -> Number -> Flat text.

(Since I'm Dutch, the options might be named slightly different - apologies for that)

Comment: For me in the US, the equivalent would be FORMAT >> NUMBER >> PLAIN TEXT. I have them all set to plain text, yet the moment the split function is used and it splits the number and text, it treats 10-09 as a number and converts it to 43017

Comment: Have you tried `SPLIT(TEXT(A1), " ")`?

Alternatively: to get just the first item after the SPLIT, try
`INDEX(SPLIT(A1; " "), 0, -1)`

Comment: so TEXT requires a 'format' and the only options refer to numbers or dates. I think what you meant was SPLIT(T(A1), " ") however, that still spits out the random numbers. If I use index, it only spits out 1 column and I need all three.
What i noticed is, if the column is set to automatic, the number splits correctly, but it thinks it's a date. If i set it back to plain text (which happens whenever I copy/paste values only, it'll spit out the 5 digit numbers.) The hypen is causing it to think it's a date and I can't seem to get googlesheets to not do that as a default behavior